# SWT ColorDialog on Mac OS always returns black color

Tags: macos, swt

We are using SWT ColorDialog to return the color that the user picked. This works fine on Windows. However, on a MAC the color returned is always black.
Color dialog on a Mac does not have OK/Cancel buttons, so we select a color and then close the dialog. Presumably this has to return the selected color. But only black color is always returned no matter color we select.

The code is pretty simple:

```
ColorDialog dlg = new ColorDialog (shell);
dlg.setText ("Select color");
RGB newRGB = dlg.open ();
if (newRGB != null)
{
    System.out.println (newRGB.toString ());
}
```

Is this a known bug? Are we doing something wrong?

Comment: This code works fine for me on macOS 10.12.6 with the SWT from Eclipse Oxygen.

Comment: I am using SWT from Eclipse Neon. Was there any bug fix since then? I couldn't find any reference to any bugs in this area

Comment: I don't think so. Eclipse itself uses this dialog (for example in the 'Colors and Fonts' Preference page) so it is unlikely that a bug would exist. Perhaps you should show us a [mcve] in case the problem is elsewhere.

Comment: We develop on Windows and then export the project for Mac and Linux. This is an E4 application. Would be hard for us to create an example you are asking for. Yet, the problem definitely exists. Maybe it's related to exporting a project? The code that doesn't work is literally the code that I have attached. I cannot see what we could have done wrong there and what could be changed to get it to work. Or maybe we are not selecting the color properly on a Mac? We just click on the color and close the dialog. Maybe we need to press an Option key as well or something like that?

Comment: I guess, the only minimal test would be to create an empty E4 application under Windows with one menu item that calls the Color dialog using the code above. Then export it to Mac and see what color it returns.

Comment: I can sort of reproduce this if I call `dlg.setRGB(new RGB(0, 0, 0))` before opening the dialog and only if I only select on the 'color wheel' selector (which appears as all black). There are no special keys for the dialog. I tried calling from my e4 RCP - still OK. No bug reports in Eclipse Bugzilla.

Comment: Did you export your e4 application from Windows to Mac?

Comment: I don't run Windows

Comment: So this can be specific to project export. The issue is clearly happening for me. I cannot see how this can be the problem of our application. This will cripple the application and I don't see a workaround. Any advice? Is there any other dialog for picking colors that can be used? Where can I get source code for this dialog?

Comment: The GIT repository for SWT is https://git.eclipse.org/c/platform/eclipse.platform.swt.git/ On macOS `ColorDialog` is just a thin wrapper for the macOS `NSColorPanel` API.

Comment: This is totally bizarre. It turns out that the behaviour of the color dialog depends on the state of the button that brings it up. The dialog is displayed from a link on the parent dialog. There is also a checkbox on the parent that enables/disables this link. If the link hasn't been disabled the color dialog works properly. But if you click on the checkbox to disable the link, then click again to enable it and then click on the link to bring up the color dialog it will always return black. Explains why noone is having this problem, but there's clearly a bizarre bug there.

Comment: Just to confirm I can reproduce this using `Link`, works OK with `Button`.

Comment: There is an easy work around then for me. Thank you for all your help.